# Evaluating survival models in the presence of covariate-dependent censoring

Tags: estimation, survival, assumptions, model-comparison, censoring

I have a censored survival analysis problem with the following characteristics:

- Failure times are discretized
- The censorship distribution depends on certain covariates
- I don't have a properly-specified model for the censorship distribution
- Censorship sometimes occurs with probability 0 or 1 depending on the covariates

I'd really like some good metrics to evaluate the survival models I build. However, all the metrics I've looked at (mostly Harrell's *c* and variants) either depend on the censorship distribution (ick!) or their estimators assume that the censorship distribution is independent of covariates, or that you have a properly-specified model for it.

Are there any evaluation criteria for survival models that don't make any of these assumptions? Or, failing that, are at least robust to their violation?